# php array of arrays to 1D array not getting properly as expected

Tags: php

I am reading value from CMD which is running a python program and my output as follows:

[image]

Let as assume those values as `$A`:

```
$A = [[1][2][3][4]....]
```

I want to make an array from that as:

```
$A = [1,2,3,4....]
```

I had tried as follows:

```
$val = str_replace("[","",$A);
$val = str_replace("]","",$val);
print_r($val);
```

I am getting output as:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 2 3 4 ... )
```

Please guide me

Comment: That's not a string. That's an array of arrays.

Comment: Show us your **real** code

Comment: @JohnConde ok. So how can I make it single dimensional array?

Comment: that is not an array, its parser error

Comment: @Rizier123 actually that value I am getting from phython and I am doing calculation here

Comment: You're trying to cut apples with a meat chopper. You're using the false tool.

Comment: @YUNOWORK can you help me to find a simple knife to cut. It will be really helpful!!

Comment: @user1989 Your input, given code and current output doesn't match. Give us an [MCVE] so we have the same code as you have

Comment: The users who published here, are right. You want to create an array of arrays. I believe that this link would be useful for you, next time try to search before to ask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570266/arraylist-in-php

Comment: Your question is very **unclear**. There are too many **unknowns** and your question is a contradiction in itself. You already got 7 completely different *"answers"* from this, which shows how unclear your question is. You need to clarify your question!

Comment: Yes its been a long time @Rizier123 but I've deleted mine. This is really been misinterpreted by everyone over here

Comment: @Rizier123 I am executing a python program in background from that I am getting the value and I am assigning it into a variable and I need to make an array from that!!'

Comment: @user1989 Read it very carefully and edit your question after it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [MCVE]

Comment: Wait I will edit my question!!

Comment: @Rizier123 I have editted my question. I hope it is clear to all now!!

Comment: @Rizier123 from the OP's comment to one of the answers: «my case it is not comma seperated it is `[[1] [2] [3] [4]]` not `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`», it seems he just wants to replace the characters of a string which content looks like an array.

Comment: @Armfoot you are spot on buddy!! That is what I needed!!

Comment: @Armfoot Could be. It's just a guess game and an unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

This function will work when you do indeed have a multidimensional array, which you stated you have, in stead of the String representation of a multidimensional array, which you seem to have.

```
function TwoDToOneDArray($TwoDArray) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($TwoDArray as $value) {
        array_push($result, $value[0]);
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(TwoDToOneDArray([[0],[1]]));
```

Comment: I got output as `array (size=1)
  0 => string '[' (length=1)`. Not working

Comment: @eroydev my array looks like `[[0][1]]` not like`[[0],[1]]`. Do not have a `comma` seperated. So your code not working!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like you wrote in the first place you can try with regex:

```
$a = '[[1][2][3][4]]';

preg_match_all('/\[([0-9\.]*)\]/', $a, $matches);
$a = $matches[1];

var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// your code goes here
$array = array(
    array("1"),
    array("2"),
    array("3"),
    array("4")
    );

$outputArray = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $outputArray[] = $value[0];     
}

print_r($outputArray);
```

Also check the example here https://ideone.com/qaxhGZ

Comment: not working at all in my case. $A = array(); Im getting null array

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional array to single dimensional array,

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($A));
$A = iterator_to_array($it, false);
```

But, if `$A` is string

```
$A = '[[1][2][3][4]]';

$A = explode('][', $A);
$A = array_map(function($val){
        return trim($val,'[]');
    }, $A);
```

Both codes will get,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Comment: Not working get warnings as `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array ` and `Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `$A = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]` into `$B = [1,2,3,4....]` using this following one line solution:

```
$B = array_map('array_shift', $A);
```

PD: You could not handle an array of arrays ( a matrix ) the way you did. That way is only for managing strings. And your notation was wrong. An array of arrays (a matrix) is declared with commas.

Comment: my case it is not comma seperated it is `[[1] [2] [3] [4]]` not `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`

Answer (score 0):

If `$A` is a string that looks like an array, here's one way to get it:

```
$A = '[[1][2][3][4]]';
print "[".str_replace(array("[","]"),array("",","),substr($A,2,strlen($A)-4))."]";
```

It removes `[` and replaces `]` with `,`. I just removed the end and start brackets before the replacement and added both of them after it finishes. [This outputs: `[1,2,3,4]` as you can see in this link](http://ideone.com/HbAjWN).